# Wordpress Pretty Permalinks redirecting to home page on iis7

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have my WP site on iis7[Windows server 2008 R2];have explored a lot to find the right solution but nothing worked :(

http://cricketclips.net/late-overs-batting-flurry-from-luke-wright-pepsi-ipl-2013-kxip-vs-pw-match-29/

Added the following code to web.config in root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="WordPress Rule" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php?page_id={R:0}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

but still it didn't work

My Url are being rewrite but are redirected to homepage instead of single.php and other pages ( that is index.php instead of single.php)

have checked the server for "FCGI" and "URL rewrite module", both are installed.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This link](http://strangelyperfect.tv/11622/wordpress-permalinks-generated-but-not-redirected/) helped me make my permlinks to work!

Just followed the steps

1. Changed the permalink structure to

   http://example.com/index.php/%post_id%/%postname%/
2. Checked the result and voila! it was working...
3. Then changed the link back to

   http://example.com/%post_id%/%postname%/
4. And happily ever after :)

Answer (score 0):

You can Change the permalink setting from here

http://localhost/{your_projects_name}/wp-admin/options-permalink.php